# How Docker container volumes work even when they aren't running?

Tags: docker

Take a typical data only Docker container:

```
FROM stackbrew/busybox:latest

RUN mkdir /data
VOLUME /data
```

Now I have seen a great deal of them that are run like this:

`docker run -name my-data data true`

The `true` command exits as soon as it runs, and so does the container. But surprisingly it continues to serve the volume when you connect it with another container via `--volumes-from my-data`.

My question is, how does that work? How does a stopped container still allow access in it's volumes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Volumes in docker are not a top-level thing. They are "simply" part of container's meta-data.

When you have `VOLUME` in your dockerfile or start a container with `-v`, Docker will create a directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`* with a random ID (this is the exact same process as creating an image with `commit` except it is empty) and add that random ID to the container's metadata.

When the container starts, Docker will mount-bind the directory `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`* at the given location for that volume.

When you use `volumes-from`, Docker will just lookup the volume id and the location from an other container, running or not and mount-bind the directory at the set location.

Volumes are not linked with the runtime, it is just directories that are mounted.

* With newer versions, Docker now uses the `vfs` driver for storage and `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` is used only for metadatas like size, create time, etc. The actual data are stored in `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/<volume id>`